# Creating queries in Portal for ArcGIS that do not have to be predefined?

Tags: query, definition-query, widget, arcgis-portal, query-task

I am trying to figure out if there is a way to make a query widget in Portal for ArcGIS that is more free form. I want to know if there is a way a user can type in queries that are not predefined. Or if there is something besides the Query widget that might accomplish this.

I am open to python scripting but would like to avoid it for time constraining reasons if possible.

Answer (score 1):

Portal 10.4+ supports free form queries using the Find Locations tools that install as part of the analysis toolkit.